# formControlName in nested input component

Tags: angular

I have a component MyForm that has HTML like this

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <app-my-input-component></app-my-input-component>
</form>
```

And in the MyInputComponent the html is

```
<input formControlName='myInput'>
```

When I do this, I get the error `formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive`

Is there any way to get this sort of structure to work with formGroups, or should I move everything into one component?

Comment: You can just pass the FormGroup or FormControl as an Input to the child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ControlContainer` to enable the form to be split up into multiple components.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlContainer,
  FormGroupDirective,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-child',
  template: `<input [formControlName]="controlName">`,
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective,
    },
  ],
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() controlName: string;
  constructor(private parent: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parent.form.addControl(
      'age',
      new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    );
  }
}
```

[Existing Stackblitz not by me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-form-with-controlcontainer-za7vtn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts)

[alternate method](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-form-child-components-controlcontainer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[reference article](https://jenniferwadella.com/blog/angular-control-container)